# Upload image in Parse.com as backend

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am able to load image gallery and display image in Imageview. I need to save the image which user selects in parse.com as blackened. Its a picturepath that I am able to load using BitmapFactory. I have created a column in data browser with field as File. I have also gone through the tutorials on Parse.com and implemented each step. But its not working when click on save button. App is crashing each time.

My Code is :

```
public class LoadImg extends Activity  {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
FrameLayout layout;
Button save ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
    if(!picturePath.equals(""))
    {
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }        
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });        
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Locate the image in res > 
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
            // Convert it to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", image);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("ImageUpload");

            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
            imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");

            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            imgupload.saveInBackground();

            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(LoadImg.this, "Image Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null  != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit();
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));                        
           } 
    }}
```

LogCat is :

> 01-05 20:43:54.678: E/JavaBinder(1298): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
>   01-05 20:44:48.418: E/AndroidRuntime(3453): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.lovy.parse.LoadImg$2.onClick(LoadImg.java:56)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2418)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4233)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6645)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3763)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   01-05 20:44:48.428: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-05 20:44:48.438: E/SemcCheckin(3453): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
>   01-05 20:44:48.508: E/SemcCheckin(1565): Get Crash Level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
>   01-05 20:44:58.378: E/ATK(2142): widget kill start

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @cYrixmorten I have edited the question above.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat message?

Comment: @cYrixmorten I have edited the code and posted the logcat. Thanx

Comment: nullpointer at com.lovy.parse.LoadImg$2.onClick(LoadImg.java:56). What is on line 56?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @cYrixmorten  Yes, I did. I'm adding an answer to it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Locate the image in res > 
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
            // Convert it to byte
            //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
            //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            try {
                image = readInFile(path);
            }
            catch(Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", image);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
            imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            imgupload.saveInBackground();

            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(LoadImg.this, "Image Saved, Upload another one ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
}

private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    byte[] data = null;
    File file = new File(path);
    InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            file));
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
    int bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
    }
    input_stream.close();
    return buffer.toByteArray();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No LogCat yet but I suspect:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.imageView1);
```

To cause problems, as R.id.imageView1 is a id to a View and not an image resource.

You could try this instead:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(picturePath);

if (bitmap != null) {
   // ...
}
```

Note:

you also have this:

```
// Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
imgupload.put("Image", R.id.imageView1);
```

From the comment, your intention is to save a String but actually you save the id Integer.